# Como faço para arredondar um número float de duas casas decimais para uma se tiver apenas um número? exemplo: 2.10 para 2.1

Tags: c

O problema é que os números tem que ter duas casas decimais sempre, só nos casos em que for tipo '3.10' tem que formatar para '3.1'. Como faço isso em C?

Comment: Números de ponto flutuante são resultados aproximados de soma de potências de 2 (positivas e negativas), então é difícil saber quando algo só deveria ser representado em um único digito após a vírgula no sistema decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O especificador de conversão `%g` é capaz de exibir somente os dígitos significativos de um tipo `float`.

Por Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    float a = 1.1230000;
    float b = 3.14150000;
    float c = 10;

    printf( "a = %g\n", a );
    printf( "b = %g\n", b );
    printf( "c = %g\n", c );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
a = 1.123
b = 3.1415
c = 10
```

Referências:

> **O especificador de conversão de saída `%g`**
>
> Os valores são exibidos no formato `%f` ou `%e`, dependendo do que for
>   mais compacto para o valor e para a precisão que foram especificados.
>   O formato `%e` só será usado quando o expoente do valor for menor do
>   que `-4` ou maior ou igual ao argumento de precisão. Zeros à esquerda
>   são truncados, e o ponto decimal é exibido somente se um ou mais
>   dígitos vierem na sequência.

Fonte: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: Tem uma fonte de leitura? Para eu me aprofundar mais?

Answer (score 0):

A outra forma de fazer isso, colocando %f.1 assim todas as vezes ele irá exibir uma casa após a vírgula mais continuara trabalhando com numero completo.

Comment: Você quis dizer `%f.1`? E poderia [edit] a resposta explicando melhor a sua sugestão, com um exemplo etc?

Comment: Ainda falta o exemplo :)

Comment: Não seria `%.1f`? Testei com `%f.1` e sempre aparece `.1` após o valor. Mas mesmo assim, utilizando apenas `%.1f`, aparecerá apenas uma casa decimal, independente do valor. Por exemplo, se eu tentar exibir 3.1415, o resultado seria 3.1, mas não é isso o pedido.

Comment: Tem razão @Anderson, eu errei duplamente